# Advanced custom Swing component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Does anyone know any good resources where I can find and use custom Swing components with more advanced functionality than the default swing. More specifically I am looking for

- DatePickers
- JTable with sorting and multicolumn filtering

Also if you know any good custom look and feels you can share that would be great. I have found several but if you know something that is good please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[swingx](/questions/tagged/swingx)

Contains extensions to the Swing GUI toolkit, including new and enhanced components that provide functionality commonly required by rich client applications. Highlights include:

- Sorting, filtering, highlighting for tables, trees, and lists
  Find/search Auto-completion Login/authentication framework TreeTable
  component Collapsible panel component Date picker component
  Tip-of-the-Day component
- See more [here](http://swingx.java.net/#sthash.nYYvML07.dpuf)

http://swingx.java.net/

Comment: Good advice. I use `SwingX` since two years and it´s excellent to me.

Comment: (biased :-) me loves answers recommending SwingX, @dic19 - and happy users

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st part - SwingX is the best solution.

For look and feels see [here](http://javootoo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find advanced components and concept for custom design here with explaination

-JXDatePicker
-JXPanel 
-JXGlassPanel 
-JXTitledPanel 
-JXHyperLink
-JXRadioGroupy
-JXRadioGroup

http://www.tutego.de/java/additional-java-swing-components.htm